# Strange macro behaviour

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Here is my piece of source code:

```
for(j=0; j<n-1; j++) {
    printf("(%d %d)->(%d) {%1.9lf < %1.9lf }\n", j+1, j, j + n*(j+1), A[j + n*(j+1)], epsilon*norm);
    printf("(%d %d)->(%d) {%1.9lf < %1.9lf }\n", j+1, j, idx(n, j+1, j), A[idx(n, j+1, j)], epsilon*norm);
    if(A[idx(n,j+1,j)] < epsilon*norm) {
        A[idx(n,j+1,j)] = 0;
    }
  }
```

Here is my idx macro:

```
#define idx(__n__, __i__, __j__) __j__ + __n__*(__i__)
```

In my opinion, 2nd, 3rd line of code must produce the same output, but it's not so. Instead I got output like this(n is equal to 5):

```
(1 0)->(5) {5.393394651 < 0.000000000 }
(1 0)->(1) {6.171880741 < 0.000000000 }
(2 1)->(11) {2.966791392 < 0.000000000 }
(2 1)->(7) {2.850418342 < 0.000000000 }
(3 2)->(17) {3.370025863 < 0.000000000 }
(3 2)->(13) {4.128639694 < 0.000000000 }
(4 3)->(23) {0.290962836 < 0.000000000 }
(4 3)->(19) {0.147772573 < 0.000000000 }
```

I tried run gcc with flag E to see what preprocessor did with code, but I saw the same lines of code.

```
for(j=0; j<n-1; j++) {
    printf("(%d %d)->(%d) {%1.9lf < %1.9lf }\n", j+1, j, j + n*(j+1), A[j + n*(j+1)], epsilon*norm);
    printf("(%d %d)->(%d) {%1.9lf < %1.9lf }\n", j+1, j, j + n*(j+1), A[j + n*(j+1)], epsilon*norm);
    if(A[j + n*(j+1)] < epsilon*norm) {
        A[j + n*(j+1)] = 0;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't use double leading underscore for symbols, those are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library) in all scopes.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3

Comment: I notice that your macro evaluation of `idx(n, j+1, j)` is always 4 less than the non-macro version `j + n*(j+1)`.

Comment: As for your problem, I'm sure you can see a pattern in the results... When using the macro the result is always 4 lower than without the macro. Also, I [can't replicate your problem](http://ideone.com/uENWvm), so it's probably something else that you don't show us.

Comment: Code works for me. I think you have a difference between what you showed us and what you actually have written down yourself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it could be related to the problem; perhaps the implementation defines those names to mean something, or implements magic for certain names

Comment: So please post the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is useless to protect macro arguments with a silly syntax such as `__i__`, and it makes the macro harder to read.  Also break your source lines to a shorter length for the same reason.

Comment: `printf` format for `double` is `%f`, not `%lf`.  No matter what is the type of `A`, this format is inappropriate.  Please post more code, a complete compilable example that shows your problem.

Comment: Based on your output as pointed out by @WeatherVane, It seems in your actual code the macro might have incorrectly reversed the position of `__i__` and `__j__`. You might have inadvertently corrected it when posting here.

Comment: I changed "_ _var_ _" notation to "var" and made properly parenthesize. It solved my problem. After this I undone changes but problem not reproduced now. Most likely it was my carelessness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro does not properly parenthesize the arguments in the expansion:

```
#define idx(__n__, __i__, __j__) __j__ + __n__*(__i__)
```

Should be:

```
#define idx(n, i, j) ((j) + (n) * (i))
```

Unless you **really** mean something crazy.

This is a bug, but not one causing your problem.  Try fixing the `printf` format for `double` to `%f` instead of `%lf`.  Also make verify the types of `j` and `n`, `A`, `epsilon` and `norm` are consistent with the `printf` formats.

Comment: The `l` modifier to `f` is silently ignored in `printf`. That's not an error.

Comment: @FUZxxl: `%lf` is accepted in `printf` as of `C99` and the `l` modifier is indeed silently ignored, it is unspecified what it means under C89.  I don't know what compiler and environment the OP uses, his code does not exhibit the unexpected behavior on my system with clang.  I agree with Weather Vane, the OP probably mistyped his submission.